# Include the character in positive lookahead in the result

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

```
Name: John
Surname: Doe
Age: 24
```

When I do

```
Regex.Replace(str,"(?<=^|\n)(.*)(?=:)", "")
```

I get

```
: John
: Doe
: 24
```

I want to get rid of the colons without using another replace

Comment: Just don't use a lookahead and match it regularily. It's also likely that you want to match the following space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `(?=:)` is a positive lookahead that is a non-consuming pattern. The `:` char is tested but it does not land inside the match value, and is thus not replaced with the `Regex.Replace` method.

You may make your pattern work by mere converting the lookahead pattern into a consuming pattern, i.e. `(?=:)` => `:`, but you may simplify your pattern using

```
(?m)^.*:
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E.*%3A%5Cs*&i=Name%3A%20John%0D%0ASurname%3A%20Doe%0D%0AAge%3A%2024&r=)

The `(?m)^` matches the start of a *line*, there is no need using `(?<=^|\n)` as it denotes exactly that.  Then, `.*:` matches any 0+ chars other than a newline as many as possible up to the last `:` and also that last `:`.

To also remove the whitespace  after `:`, you may add `\s*`, or (if you want to only handle horizontal whitespace chars) `[\p{Zs}\t]*`.

Answer (score -1):

Swap the positive lookahead for a negative lookahead.